# Source can only be set from xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am setting the source property of ResourceDictionary programatically and not from xaml in a Xamarin forms project.

During run time I always get System.invalidOperation exception with the message "Source can only be set from Xaml.

```
Resources = Resources ?? new ResourceDictionary();
    if(Resources.Source == null)
                {
                    Resources.Source = new Uri("/Styles/ActiveTrackerStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                }
```

Wondering if I am doing anything wrong while setting the Source. Source property has both getter and setter. Any pointers of what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a colleague, I got it working:

First: Browsing through the Xamarin.Forms' ResourceDictionary class ([here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/ResourceDictionary.cs), I saw the following property:

```
public Uri Source {
            get { return _source; }
            set {
                if (_source == value)
                    return;
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Source can only be set from XAML."); //through the RDSourceTypeConverter
}
```

It seems that you cannot change the source if the private variable "_source" has been set already;

However, the class also have another method "SetAndLoadSource" and in this method the _source variable is set without any checks. Thus, I got it working by doing the following:

```
var source = new Uri("/Styles/LightResourceDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
resourceDictionary.SetAndLoadSource(source, "Styles/LightResourceDictionary.xaml", this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly, null);
ThemeDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
ThemeDictionary.MergedDictionaries.ElementAt(0).Source = source;
```

Note that "ThemeDictionary" is the x:Name of my MergedDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="ThemeDictionary">
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/DarkResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
```